# Angular not working locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a simple functionality to test AngularJS and it is not working on Chrome, Mozilla nor Safari on Mac OSX. 
I am guessing that a problem is with ng-controller since ng-model is working fine. 
Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the main.js file:

```
function myController($scope) {

    $scope.author = {
        'name' : 'The Name',
        title : 'The title',
        company : 'The Company Name'

    }
}
```

So if someone could point me to the problem it would be great...

Comment: you forgot add `ng-app` for view.

Comment: Documentation for ng app - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: how did ng-model work without ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

Every Angular app requires an `ng-app` directive to pinpoint the root element in which angular will run.

In your case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is better to declare your app name (module name) and then assign it to the `ng-app` directive.